# Some how all sorts of test argument flags showing up in go program usage

Tags: go

I have a small go command line utility that I am building in the usual way:

```
go build
```

I use the `flag` package to add command line flags. And all was going swimmingly until I started getting a lot of test flags showing up. Now when I print the usage using `flag.Usage` I see lots of extra flags:

```
  -test.bench string
        regular expression to select benchmarks to run
  -test.benchmem
        print memory allocations for benchmarks
  -test.benchtime duration
        approximate run time for each benchmark (default 1s)
  -test.blockprofile string
        write a goroutine blocking profile to the named file after execution
  -test.blockprofilerate int
        if >= 0, calls runtime.SetBlockProfileRate() (default 1)
```

There are a lot more than this.

I am using the main flag set and adding flags with `flag.IntVar` and the like.

I can't figure out what I did or how this could have been enabled. None of my other programs include these test flags in the default usage message. I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hm... `grep testing $(ls *.go | grep -v '_test.go')` doesn't turn up anything. How does go make the decision about whether to compile in `*_test.go` files?

Comment: Ah. You were right. I was referencing testing in a dependency of my package, so my grep didn't pick it up. Want to submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `testing` package's `init()` adds command line arguments to your app using the flags package.

You are likely referencing `testing` from some bit of non-testing code.